# Checking a string in a variable in python

Tags: python, json, string, api

I'm trying to process some data from twitch API to check whether a channel is live or not from a json list like that:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("http://some-api/api", params)

rdata = r.json()

rstatus = rdata["live"]
```

`rstatus` returns me "None" string for being offline otherwise it do not returns. So what I want is checking if `rstatus` is "None" or something different from "None" string. I tried this code but didn't worked:

```
if "None" in rstatus:
    print("Live")
else:
    print("Offline")
```

Comment: `if rstatus is None: ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see 'None' printed, it is Python's way of telling you rstatus does not exist. It's like 'null' in other languages. It's not a string, it's literally nothing. You can do:

```
if rstatus is None:
    foo
else:
    bar
```

'is None' is the preferred way of doing it. It's faster and more accepted than `rstatus == none`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

It's simple:

```
>>> status = None
>>> if status:
...   print "it live, status is not None"
... else:
...   print "too sad..."
...
too sad...
>>>
```

But the Zen of Python says, "*Explicit is better than implicit.*". Test if status is None:

```
>>> if not status == None:
...   print "it live, status is not None"
... else:
...   print "too sad..."
...
too sad...
>>>
```

Comment: `if status is not None`

Comment: The first rule listed in the "Zen of Python is "Beautiful is better than ugly". :)